# Species modification

Tags: creature-design, space-colonization, genetic-engineering, empire-building

Let's say for purely cosmetic reasons, a group of people on Earth who wanted to colonize other worlds to form some kind of galactic empire decided to modify their outward appearance. Prior to doing that, they want to become one homogeneous monolithic entity distinct from all other groups of people on Earth, as they are people from different groups and regions, but with the same political ideology and goal. So like people from different races but they have the same beliefs and want to distinguish themselves from humans, seeing themselves as morally superior to Earth humans in ideology.

So, for the sake of the scenario and my novel idea, let's say this group is looking at a few things like Argyria from colloidal silver to become a bluish grey people, hybridizing with glowworms using CRISPR to become bioluminescent, potential plastic surgeries to artificially make some uniform phenotype appearance and also looking at ways to become superhuman in terms of intellect, speed and strength. Basically an artificially invoked species divergence from Homo Sapiens, into something new and more powerful and predatory that would expand beyond Earth, with the intent of space colonization. Being as realistic as possible (scientifically accurate), what are the implications of this politically and also what are some processes they could initiate to modify members of their faction with?

Would it lead to discrimination again members of the pro-space empire faction of humans?

Ethics committees trying to prevent this?

Would said group fail due to being demonized for their agenda?

Could it lead to wars before they even got off Earth?

Could they use chlorophyll to make themselves green?

Could they use luciferin to make themselves glow?

What difficulties would they have in an attempt to make themselves look different from Earth humans?

What processes are feasible with today's science, just to change the skin tone, eye colors, or to make them glow 24/7?

Comment: There is a lot of stuff to unpack here!  Maybe split this into a few questions: how feasible is it to edit a population's genes, what are common social effects of starting anew social/genetic group, and so on.

Comment: We have a strict one question per post policy. I count at least 9. Please take a moment to visit our help center and understand how our site works before you [edit] your question down to a single specific, ask.

Comment: So, the question is 'What if Star-Bellied Sneetches were real', basically?

Comment: For future reference, you're supposed to ask one and only one question.  You're asking 8, and a couple of them aren't very objective (a requirement for Stack Exchange). You're also asking two very different primary questions: how to do it and how would people react? The former we're pretty good at (have you searched our site for "blue skin" or "argyria"? We've already answered most of what you're asking). The latter is story-based, which we don't do. Will people be racist? Of course some will. Will they demonize? Of course, some will. Will it cause war? Of course. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... But the point is, that's really up to you and your story. All cultures discriminate, it's a question of what they discriminate against. Some discriminate against skin color more than others. Some poverty. Some gender. Some religion... What your society does is wholly up to you. The only unrealistic answer would be no discrimination at all (birds of a feather...). So, we help you build world rules (in your case, creature design) but we don't help you tell stories. Unless you ask in our Chat, the Factory Floor. You can ask anything there.

Comment: BTW, I was the last vote to close the question. Please don't take that personally! It might not feel like it, but what we're doing is giving you a chance to [edit] your question to both conform with SE's and our own rules (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]) and to improve its focus and usefulness to you (like giving you a chance to [search for Argyria](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+Argyria+)...). Let us help you understand how to craft a fabulous Q and you'll have more fun on the Stack.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, also, I understand.